# Umbraco running on a Load Balanced IIS 7.5 configuration

Tags: umbraco, iis-7.5, load-balancing

I have an Umbraco website that is running on IIS7.5 and is Load Balanced.  The users are updating via one side only so that we don't get any issues whilst updating the site.  The problem is, each day we have to force a restart of the website by touching the web.config file.  If we don't touch the web.config file, the users are displayed with an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.  I have configured the DistributedCall element in the umbracoSettings config file, but can't figure out why I have to keep restarting the website.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried tweeting this to @umbraco, they often reply really quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, but I've managed to get this working by changing the Regular Interval Time in the Application Pool.